# MarkLogic Corb job fail during the process cause by file too large

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-corb

The corb job runs over million of records but fail one of the file is too large.  I have check diskspace still available over 10TB.  I couldn't figure why corb reject a large record. Thanks in advance.

```
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XQueryException: SVC-FILOPN: 
xdmp:save("/output/147362/DAC-033595.xml", <handle:record 
xmlns:mdr="http://nfiw.org/record"><meta:Metadata .../>...</handle:record>) -- 
File open error: open '/output/147362/DAC-033595.xml': **File too 
large**

at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.ServerExceptionHandler.handleResponse(ServerExceptionHandler.java:34)
    at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.EvalRequestController.serverDialog(EvalRequestController.java:86)
    at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.AbstractRequestController.runRequest(AbstractRequestController.java:86)
    at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.SessionImpl.submitRequestInternal(SessionImpl.java:401)
    at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.SessionImpl.submitRequest(SessionImpl.java:372)
    at com.marklogic.developer.corb.AbstractTask.invokeModule(AbstractTask.java:227)
```

Comment: The SVC-FILOPN error is telling you the OS reported a problem. https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/messages/SVC-en/SVC-FILOPN File too large is sometimes reported when out of space. Why use xdmp:save() in the process module saving on ML instead of having CoRB write?

Comment: Does it always fail on the same document? Any idea how large that document really is? To be clear, CoRB isn't rejecting the document, there is an XCC error from a MarkLogic server error SVC-FILOPN. MarkLogic wasn't able to save that document in the transaction and threw an exception for that transaction.